# How to combine date object and time object into DateTime object and store in google sheet as DateTime object

Tags: date, datetime, google-apps-script, time

I have a date object and a time object that I want to combine into a datetime object, not as a string but as a datetime object that I can store to later test against other datetime objects.  All questions like this appear to deal with string formats of datetime.

I tried simply adding the two objects together which works for two elements of a sheet but does not work for script variables.

```
var lastDayPumpOn = new Date();
lastDayPumpOn = lastPumpDate + lastPumpTime;
Browser.msgBox('Last on time = '+lastDayPumpOn);
```

This simple addition produces something that appears to be a concatenation of the date with zero time and a time with zero date. It's not clear to me if it is actually a datetime object or some string.

Comment: `lastPumpTime` seems to be a `string`. Where did you get it?

Comment: lastPumpDate was read from a sheet where the value was constructed from a full date by "int(lastDate). lastPumpTime was read from the sheet as constructed by "mod(lastDate,1)". I'm trying to reconstruct the full lastDate to store in a different sheet.

Comment: Why not refer the actual `lastDate` in the sheet then, which contains both date and time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "time" or "datetime" object in JavaScript, just [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

**Why you get a string, not a new date**

If you want to add the [milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) stored inside your Date objects together, you have to take care that both arguments are indeed `Date` objects or numbers (representing milliseconds), and get the milliseconds with either `.getTime()` or prefix a `+` to the variable.

```js
// this assumes lastPumpTime is some Date that has had its date component "zeroed out"
var lastDayPumpOn = new Date(lastPumpDate.getTime() + lastPumpTime.getTime()); // construct new Date from milliseconds argument
// or
var lastDayPumpOnAlt = new Date(+lastPumpDate + +lastPumpTime); // implicitly using Date.prototype.valueOf
// lastDayPumpOn.getTime() === lastDayPumpOnAlt.getTime() is true
Browser.msgBox('Last on time = ' + lastDayPumpOn); // implicitly calls lastDayPumpOn.toString()
```

If either variable around a `+` is a string, then the result will be a string.  Any objects will have their `.toString` function called implicitly.

**Zeroing out date part**

To create your "time" object (Date without the date part), there are various methods, one of which is to just set the date part to Jan 1, 1970

```js
lastPumpTime.setFullYear(1970);
lastPumpTime.setMonth(0); // Jan === 0, zero indexed
lastPumpTime.setDate(1);
```

Now `lastPumpTime.getTime()` is some milliseconds less than 24 hours worth of milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but got a message “Invalid Date”. It didn’t come from the “new Date” line but from the msgBox. I then added a msgBox to display the two values passed to “new Date”. That yielded “Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) Sat Dec 30 1899 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)”. Both contain full date & time and it appears that “new Date” can’t handle that.

Comment: @AlexanderGrillo  `lastPumpTime` should just be a number that represents milliseconds.  You can either subtract two dates to get this smaller number, or just use plain numbers in milliseconds.

Comment: I tried something similar attempting to mimic how the values were created in sheets originally. I changed the calculation to: lastDayPumpOn = new Date(+(Math.floor(lastPumpDate)) +(lastPumpTime - Math.floor(lastPumpTime))). The result included the correct date but the time was 00:00, not the correct time. In hind sight, I don’t know why the date was correct if the entire date object is the total milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: OK. I'm beginning to understand more now. My attempt to truncate the date did nothing since the time portion that object was already "00:00". So I will have to have a way to nullify the date portion of the time object in order for the sum of the two to work.

Comment: @AlexanderGrillo - yes, I added once such truncating method in my answer - there are others.

Comment: Thanks for the second suggestion.  It makes good sense, but when I tried it, I still get "Invalid" Date" when I tried it.  I verified that my time object now has 1-Jan-1970 as its date part, but when I include that in the "new Date" function, I get "invalid data" which I try to display the result with msgBox or store it back into the sheet.

Comment: @AlexanderGrillo - make sure your argument to `new Date` is a number, e.g. `new Date(someDate.getTime() + zeroedDateOnlyTime.getTime())`.  Or try it separately `var milliseconds = someDate.getTime() + zeroedDateOnlyTime.getTime();` and verify with `typeof milliseconds === "number"`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work so I thought I should list the working code in case others might find it useful.  Perhaps my requirement is very unusual since I could not find a similar example.  All other examples to combine date and time dealt with string formatted dates and times.
I learned a lot about date manipulation by this exercise.  dwmorrin was a great help.  The last surprise was the need to correct the time zone.  I found that the time fixing left the result in GMT zone, well actually GMT offset by daylight savings time shift.  My use of getTimezoneOffset may not be the most general method to account for this but it works for my time zone.
Thank you again dwmorrin.

```
    // The variables lastPumpDate and lastPumpTime are a date and time read from two columns of 
    // dates and times that had been at some earlier time deconstructed from a column of full 
    // date-time objects using the spreadsheet functions int(date) and mod(date,1).  
    // This code segment of a script is to reconstruct the full date-time object to be stored in another 
    // sheet for further processing.  
    Var lastPumpTimeFixed = lastPumpTime;  // Time object must have date component cleared
    lastPumpTimeFixed.setFullYear(1970);       // This done by setting it to base date
    lastPumpTimeFixed.setMonth(0);
    lastPumpTimeFixed.setDate(1);
    var valTimezoneOffset = lastPumpTime.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
    var lastDayPumpOn = new Date(+lastPumpDate.getTime() +lastPumpTimeFixed.getTime() - valTimezoneOffset);
```

A bit further explanation for this solution: The date-only object lastPumpDate was read from an existing Google sheet by a .getValues() function which also added a timezone offset that didn’t exist in the sheet cell.  This set the time of the script variable to the equivalent UTC if/when it would be combined with a time object.  This timezone offset was based upon the timezone of the running script and included any adjustment for daylight savings time based on the date read.  The time-only object lastPumpTime was likewise read from the pre-existing sheet using the .getValues() function which also added a timezone offset that may not have existed in the sheet cell, I didn’t dig that far to be sure. This timezone offset was also correct for the time zone of the running script to set the time to the equivalent UTC but without any adjustment for daylight savings time since its date was unknown.  Therefore, when adding the date-only object to the time-only object in the “new Date” operation, the result had two timezone offsets, one adjusted for daylight savings time and one not.  That is the reason that one offset had to be subtracted and it must be the one associated with the time-only object, which did not include a daylight savings adjustment.  Then when a later part of the script put the resultant full date-time object into a new sheet, the remaining offset was effectively un-applied leaving the time of the full date-time cell the same as that of the original time-only cell.  I cannot say for sure what would happen if the final sheet is in a different timezone from the original sheet, but I imagine that a different adjustment might be applied leaving the time of the full date-time cell with same UTC as the original but adjusted for the different timezone.